# React native multiple select items

Tags: arrays, react-native, select, drop-down-menu, state

I have a drop-down menu where I can select multiple items and then using those values I am changing the state of an array where I have loaded some data from a server, so, after those data are changed based on my selections, my flatlist will display those respective ones only and not all like it did before I made the selecting.
The problem is that after I remove the selections, the flatlist is not being populated with all data like before. Here is the function where I am doing all that:

```
onSelectedItemsChange = selectedItems => {

    this.setState({ selectedItems });
    var newDataArray = [];
    for (i = 0; i < selectedItems.length; i++) {

        for (j = 0; j < this.state.All.length; j++) {

            if (selectedItems[i] === this.state.All[j].type) {
                const newData = this.state.All[j];
                newDataArray.push(newData);
                this.setState({
                    All: newDataArray    //"All" is an array where I load all  data and here I am populating it with new data based on the user selection
                });

                console.log(newDataArray);
            }
        }
    }
};
```

**EDIT**

```
 <MultiSelect
                        hideTags
                        items={this.filter_pref}
                        uniqueKey="name"
                        ref={(component) => { this.multiSelect = component }}
                        onSelectedItemsChange={this.onSelectedItemsChange}
                        selectedItems={selectedItems}
                        selectText="Pick Items"
                        searchInputPlaceholderText="Search Items..."
                        onChangeInput={(text) => console.log(text)}
                        altFontFamily="ProximaNova-Light"
                        tagRemoveIconColor="#CCC"
                        tagBorderColor="#CCC"
                        tagTextColor="#CCC"
                        selectedItemTextColor="#CCC"
                        selectedItemIconColor="#CCC"
                        itemTextColor="#000"
                        displayKey="name"
                        searchInputStyle={{ color: '#CCC' }}
                        submitButtonColor="#CCC"
                        submitButtonText="Submit"
                    />
```

Comment: How do you remove the selections? Can you share that part, too?

Comment: @aytek I have just edited the question. The removal is done by the component.